# Limit with parameter

Tags: calculus

I have problem with following limit:

Let $x\in[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)=\displaystyle n^3x^n(1-x)^4$ find $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$

Comment: What have you tried? As a hint, look separately at the cases $x=1$ (for which $f_n(1)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$) and $x\in[0,1)$ (for which $x^n$ goes to $0$ "very fast").

Comment: I don't have idea what can be useful here

Comment: $n^k x^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for any $x\in (-1,1)$, and any fixed $k \geq 0$ (the exponential decays much faster than the polynomial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the interval $I=[0,1]$ we have that $f_n(x)$ is a non-negative differentiable function. Since:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log f_n(x) = \frac{n}{x}-\frac{4}{1-x} \tag{1} $$ 
the maximum of $f_n(x)$ over $I$ occurs at $x=\frac{n}{n+4}$. That leads to:
$$\forall x\in I,\qquad 0\leq f_n(x)\leq f_n\left(\frac{n}{n+4}\right) = \frac{256}{n+4}\left(\frac{n}{n+4}\right)^{n+3}\leq\frac{256}{n\,e^4}\tag{2}$$
hence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly (hence pointwise) convergent to zero on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write $\displaystyle n^3x^n$ with exponentials, keeping in mind that $x\in[0,1]$. You can put apart the case $x=0$.

Comment: It's the case $x=1$ that is problematic here...

Comment: Using exponentials, you get $\exp(n*\log(x)) $, which requires $x>0$. None of the cases $x=0$ and $x=1$ are problematic, they're just trivial.

Comment: The expression you wrote above becomes $n^3$ when $x=1$. This does not go to $0$ as the original $f_n(x)$ does (and is not the expression written by the OP, which *has* $f_n(1)=0$).

Comment: I was only talking about the left part of the expression. As I said, the case $x=1$ is trivial, the difficulty does not reside here.

Comment: My point is that you cannot "write $f_n$" as you suggest -- it's a different function you want to analayze, $f_n$ has another definition (and behavior at $x=1$). And you cannot expect that discarding a case analysis "because it's easy" without stating it to the OP is OK -- it only makes the answer confusing.

Comment: You're right I shouldn't have written $f_n$... Sorry OP if it confused you, my mistake.